# Random number in Uppaal

Tags: random, numbers, uppaal

How can I create a random number when I define a global declaration in an Uppaal program?

I want to have a variable that contains a random number as in a C program:

```c
int x = rand (100);
```

Answer (score 5):

According to folks at [Uppaal mailing list](http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/uppaal/conversations/topics/1693) , this code snippet `select: i : int[0,3]`

> will non-deterministically bind i to an integer in the range 0 to 3.

So, in Your case just use `select: x : int[0, 100]`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the proper answer is: it is not possible when defining the global declaration.

The syntax that @Kamiccolo provided I think is misleading: there does not exist a syntactic construct like "select: ..." in Uppaal.

The only possible way, at now, is:

- add a global variable "int x = 0;"
- add an initial transition whose "select" clause assign "x : int[0,100]", as the mailing list (and the manual) suggest